# Unable to close Google Admob Ads in iOS 13.3.1 : Console log: [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, admob

Unable to close Google Admob Ads in iOS 13.3.1 with Admob SDK GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.56.0

Here is worked Code. Its showing ads also…but not able to close ad.

```
-(void)showAdmobAdsFullScreen
{
        GADInterstitial * interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:ADMOB_FULL_SCREEM];
        interstitial_.delegate = self;
        [interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self.viewController];
}

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
  //  printf("Error\n");
}
```

Also Getting console log 
**[Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1**

[image]

[image]

When I press CLOSE button ad not close...but when I press corner then it close..STRANGE. How players know it must be pressed!

If anyone know how to solve console log then please reply

Comment: There's nothing you can do about that, imo, you just need to a. wait for Google to release patches. b. test ad on a real device. c. better yet, test real ad on a real device even just once (if you're against this, download your latest build from the App Store)..

Comment: @Glenn Thanks for your reply.